# Issue Marshalling C# Structure to call C .DLL

Tags: c#, marshalling

I'm having difficulty trying to marshal a structure I've defined in a C# program that is required for calling an unmanaged C .DLL file I do not have access to the source code for. A sample unmanaged C program C program can call this .DLL with no issue. The problem structure is fa_keylist below. There are multiple sub structures contained in the structure I am having issues with:

From the C header file:

```
struct fa_keypart {
    short kp_start;                      
    short kp_leng;                       
    long  kp_flags;                    
};


struct fa_keydesc {
    long  k_flags;                       
    long  k_nparts;                      
    struct fa_keypart k_part [FA_NPARTS];                                        
};


struct fa_keylist {
    long  kl_nkeys;                     
    char  kl_reserve[4];                
    struct fa_keydesc *kl_key [FA_NKEYS];
}
```

In C#, I have this defined as:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct fa_keypart
    {
        public Int16 kp_start;                            
        public Int16 kp_leng;                                       
        public Int32 kp_flags;                      
    }


    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct fa_keydesc
    {
        public Int32 k_flags;                            
        public Int32 k_nparts;                                
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray)]
        public fa_keypart[] kparts;
    };


    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct fa_keylist
    {
        public Int32 kl_nkeys;                                  
        public UInt32 kl_reserve;                              
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray)]
        public fa_keydesc[] kl_keys;    
    }
```

The DLLIMPORT signature for the actual call is defined as:

```
    [STAThread]
    [DllImport("F4AGFCFA.dll", EntryPoint = "cobfa_open", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern Int32 cobfa_open(
                        string fileName,
                        Int32 openFlags,
                        ref fa_keylist keyList,
                        Int32 recordLength);
```

The call to the function is coded as:

```
handle = cobfa_open(filename, fileFlags, ref keyList, 80);
```

I've tried a number of different Marshalling options by the way. The current error I receive is an Access Violation (Attempt to read or write protected memory).

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to declare fa_keydesc as a class to get an array of pointers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the size for the arrays.  Assuming that `FA_NPARTS` in C is 128, you could do the following:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct fa_keydesc
{
    public Int32 k_flags;                            
    public Int32 k_nparts;                                
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 128)]
    public fa_keypart[] kparts;
};
```

`UnmanagedType.ByValArray` only works with `SizeConst` set as well.

Comment: Tried this and same problem unfortunately

Comment: So the Answer above does not seem to help. I had already tried this approach. Does anyone know if there are any advanced debugging techniques available in Visual Studio to try to ascertain what C# is actually outputting and trying to hand to to an unmanaged .DLL for which there is no source code or debugging information available?